# Concatenate a variable number of lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation

Let's say a variable number of lists has been given, 5 for example, but one can enter any number of lists: `[1,2] + [3,4,5] + [6,7,8,9] + [10,11] + [12,13,14] equals L.` should give the following list inside the variable `L`: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]`.

Here's my code for the concatenation of two lists:

```
joinLists([FLH|FLT], SL, [FLH|RLT]):-
  joinLists(FLT, SL, RLT).
  joinLists([], H, H).

:-op(500, xfx, +).
:-op(600, yfx, equals).

X + Y equals Z:-
  joinLists(X, Y, Z).
```

`[1,2,3] + [4,5,6,7] equals L.` gives `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, but how to solve the problem for an indefinite number of lists?

Comment: You are redefining the priorities of `+` which is a standard operator! This will inevitably lead to numerous problems. Better leave it at the original definition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your operators declaration is incorrect, the sum should be associative (i also change the symbols, just to fit my aesthetic preference, and to avoid changing the behaviour of standard +/2):

```
:-op(500, xfy, ++).
:-op(600, xfx, cat).
```

then you can write

```
L1 ++ R cat C :- !, R cat R1, append(L1, R1, C).
L cat L .
```

test

```
?- [1,2,3]++[4,5,6]++[7,8,9] cat X.
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```

I don't see any convenience in such definition, consider that SWI-Prolog append/2 source is available...